# OBS is not recording applications file menus

Tags: screen-recorder

The Open Broadcasting Software recording applications fine (which is what I want it to) but when I click on a file menu (such as edit, view, file, help, etc) it records the button pressed but not the resultant menu. Instead it just records whatever would be behind the menu if it was not open.

[image: This is what I want OBS to record, but it is not recording it]

This is what I want OBS to record, but it is not recording it. I have windows aero disabled, but if its enabled it only records about 1/8 of the screen, which is not what I want.

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had to click the "enable aero" button in the options.